# AvalonDock 2.0: adding LayoutDocument not working after Deserialize layout

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

Simple AvalonDock application with only LayoutDocumentPane.
[image: Program sample]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow1" x:Class="AvalonTest2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="MainWindow1_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="New Tab" Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="NewTabClick"/>
            <Button Content="Save layout" Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </ToolBar>

        <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" Grid.Row="1">
            <xcad:LayoutRoot x:Name="_layoutRoot">
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="_layoutPanel">
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane x:Name="workSpace">
                        <xcad:LayoutDocument ContentId="dummy" Title="Dummy" >
                            <Button x:Name="dummyButton" Content="Dummy Content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot>
        </xcad:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout;
using Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.Serialization;

namespace AvalonTest2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NewTabClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ld = new LayoutDocument();
            var x = new Random().Next().ToString();
            ld.Title = x;
            ld.ContentId = x;
             workSpace.Children.Add(ld);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var layoutSerial = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockManager);
            layoutSerial.Serialize("layout.xml");
        }

        private void MainWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists("layout.xml"))
            {
               // var serializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockManager);
               // serializer.Deserialize("layout.xml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I press "New tab" button and everything is fine: new tab appears.

I restart the program, save layout ("Save layout" button), close program and remove comments on Deserialize lines.

I start the program and on pressing "New tab", no tabs appears. I'd look inside LayoutDocumentPane (workSpace), "Children" property is filled with new Documents.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the (de-)serializing functionality is implemented not very nice in the `AvalonDock` suite.

On deserializing, a completely new `LayoutRoot` object will be created. You define in XAML a `LayoutDocumentPane` with name `workSpace` and add the newly created `LayoutDocument` into this pane. But, after deserialization, this `LayoutDocumentPane` does not belong to the layout anymore - it has been removed; a new `LayoutDocumentPane` has been created instead.

Therefore you cannot see any `LayoutDocument` views added into the `workSpace` container.

Don't reference the instance of your `LayoutDocumentPane` by name, but rather find it dynamically instead. You have to change your code to something like:

```
var ld = new LayoutDocument();
var x = new Random().Next().ToString();
ld.Title = x;
ld.ContentId = x;

LayoutDocumentPane documentPane = this.dockManager.Layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().SingleOrDefault();
if (documentPane != null)
{
    documentPane.Children.Add(ld);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found that we had the same issue in the 1.x version, but we forget about it... :(

Comment: I had the same exact issue, and this solution is a fantastic workaround!

Answer (score 0):

Since [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174936/2132114) saved me from completely ditching Avalon Dock, I figured I would provide the VB solution here as well.  The only minor edit I made was to change *SingleOrDefault* to *FirstOrDefault*:

```
Dim documentPane As LayoutDocumentPane = me.dockManager.Layout.Descendents().OfType(Of LayoutDocumentPane).FirstOrDefault()
If Not IsNothing(documentPane) Then
    documentPane.Children.Add(ld)
End If
```